# Does Personal Notification (1 to 1 communication with bot) support reply conversation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

So I have been working on a new feature to enable both personal channel and team channel to have nested communication. Something like this
[image]

Now, the team's channel nested notifications are working OK thanks to the Conversations.replyToActivity Method. But the personal notification (1 to 1 communication with bot) has refused to work, replyToActivity fails are it defaults to  SendToConversation.

Now I have heard in so many cases where personal notification supports nested notifications, so I don't believe that it's a support issue.

Secondly, I feel its the channel Id issue, though I don't have full evidence but check this out.

Now team channel ID looks like this - 19:3b9ea9dcc6424ffab8c5bd79e240cf04@thread.tacv2
which personal notification channel Id looks like this - 29:1bONF3Q9q0IWowMFn5JPF9tgzJZYiP3xvxAKHytRU-wvE_p7A6eQccvpPrs6erlVa0Hd_S9vO7eeybBz5uKVdsg

From my research i think the personal notification channelId is a combination of appId and userId which obviously is not a valid channel Id but still it sends notification to this personal channel.

My Question:

1. Does personal notifications  (1 to 1 communication with bot) support nested notifications?
2. If Yes, please is there a hack to make this happen because the documentation does not say much about this information.

Answer (score 0):

Only group conversations in Teams support conversation threads (nested messages). 1-1 chats do not support this feature.